# How to access a prop in a layout component if my component is being passed to the layout component as a chilren prop in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I have a `Layout` component that contains a state called `isLightMode`, which I would like to pass as a prop for other components to access and use.

Here is my `Layout` component:

```
import React from 'react'
import Main from '../components/main'

export default class Layout extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { isLightMode: true }
    this.toggleTheme = this.toggleTheme.bind(this)
  }

  toggleTheme() {
    this.setState(state => ({
      isLightMode: !state.isLightMode,
    }))
  }

  render() {
    const { isLightMode } = this.state
    const { children } = this.props
    return (
      <div>
        <Navigation
          isLightMode={isLightMode}
          onToggleTheme={this.toggleTheme}
        />
        {children && <Main isLightMode={isLightMode}>{children}</Main>}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

In particular, I have a `Home` component that I would like to access the `isLightMode` prop:

```
import React from 'react'
import Layout from '../layouts/layout'
import AvatarLight from '../../content/assets/img/avatar-light.png'
import AvatarDark from '../../content/assets/img/avatar-dark.svg'

const Home = props => {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <img src={props.isLightMode ? AvatarLight : AvatarDark} />
    </Layout>
  )
}
export default Home
```

And here is my `Main` component where I can access `props.isLightMode`, but I want to access it from `Home` component:

```
import React from 'react'

const Main = (props) => {
  return (
    <main className="main">
      <div>lightmode:{props.isLightMode}</div>
      <div className="container">{props.children}</div>
    </main>
  )
}
export default Main
```

So how can I access the `isLightMode` prop that is in the `Layout` component from my `Home` component?

Comment: You have to either pass the prop down through components (known as prop drilling), or use the context API https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html.

Comment: @Tom - So before context API, there would be no way for me to access `isLightMode` from `Home` component since I am not passing the prop directly from `Layout` to `Home`? Just trying to understand if there are also other possible ways (even if they are less efficient) than Context API

Comment: You could also use Redux but again, that uses the context API. The only other way is prop drilling.

Comment: you can make use of React hook's [`useContext`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext)

Answer (score 3):

### Context

Use [`createContext`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#reactcreatecontext) to wrap all components that you need to access the state.
And [consume it via `Consumer`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextconsumer) (much cleaner with hooks).

```
const Theme = React.createContext({ isLightMode: true });

// Consume the context in Home and in Layout
const App = () => (
  <Theme.Provider>
    <Home />
  </Theme.Provider>
);
```

---

### Pass reference

This is an example with hooks, can be achieved with classes.

```js
const Home = props => {
  const isLightRef = createRef(false);
  // In layout call props.isLightPref.current = true / false.
  return (
    <Layout isLighRef={isLightRef}>
      <img src={isLightRef.current ? AvatarLight : AvatarDark} />
    </Layout>
  );
};
```

---

### Pass properties

```
Home
  --- Layout
         --- Navigation
         --- Main
```

How your code is structured `isLightMode` needs to be in `Home` so it will be in scope for `Layout` too:

```js
export default class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { isLightMode: true };
    this.toggleTheme = this.toggleTheme.bind(this);
  }

  toggleTheme() {
    this.setState(state => ({
      isLightMode: !state.isLightMode
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Layout isLightMode={this.toggleTheme} toggleTheme={this.toggleTheme}>
        <img src={this.isLightMode ? AvatarLight : AvatarDark} />
      </Layout>
    );
  }
}

const Layout = ({ children, isLightMode }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Navigation isLightMode={isLightMode} onToggleTheme={this.toggleTheme} />
      {children && <Main isLightMode={isLightMode}>{children}</Main>}
    </div>
  );
};
```

---

### State Manager

When context becomes too overwhelming you should consider using state managing libraries like [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) and [MobX](https://mobx.js.org/intro/overview.html).

Comment: i don't think your solution to move state from `Layout` to `Home` will work in my case. The reason why `isLightMode` state is in `Layout` is because I am [lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) from 'Navigation' component to 'Layout' component so I can also use `isLightMode` prop in `Home` component.

Comment: Do you mean `Navigation` renders `Home`? I can't guess that

Comment: How exactly you "lifting up" state using navigation I wonder. As I see it `Home` renders all your components

Comment: No, take a look at my `Layout` code. `Layout` renders `Navigation`. I have a bunch of components `Home`, `About`, `Blog` that all use `Layout` (see my code for `Home` to see how I use `Layout`). Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I edited my answer, still about the passing properties you only can achieve it by lifting up the state to parent `Home`.

Comment: Thanks Dennis, I think your Context and Pass properties solutions would work. Let me get back after some more reading/code-experimenting.

Comment: @DennisVash according to any one of the above solutions, he will have to shift the toggleTheme functionality to Home, but if he wants to use it in other components like About, Blog that use Layout and wants isLightMode then it won't be possible because isLightMode will be available via props or context only. But with the callback solution, isLightMode will be available to all the Parent component that will be using Layout. Or he will have to use any StateManager, which is a lot of hassle for this problem. So again look into the problem statement and suggest what could be the best solution.

Comment: @DennisVash - Thank you. The Context API is exactly what I need. BTW, I am using the static class field (i.e., `static contextType = ThemeContext`) instead of `Context.Consumer`.

Answer (score 1):

The better way is to make context and consumer from there. But you can use [React.cloneElement](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement) for passing data :

So in your case, you can do something like this :

```
class Layout extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { isLightMode: true };
    this.toggleTheme = this.toggleTheme.bind(this);
  }

  toggleTheme() {
    this.setState(state => ({
      isLightMode: !state.isLightMode
    }));
  }

  render() {
    const { isLightMode } = this.state;
    const { children } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>{children && <Main isLightMode={isLightMode}>{children}</Main>}</div>
    );
  }
}
```

And in your home component you can consume directly :

```
const Main = props => {
  return (
    <main className="main">
      <div>lightmode:{String(props.isLightMode)}</div>
      <div className="container">
        {React.cloneElement(props.children, props)} // pass props data to children
      </div>
    </main>
  );
};
const Home = props => {
  return <>{props.isLightMode ? "AvatarLight" : "AvatarDark"}</>;
};
```

Here is working link : https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-resonance-x69gm

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. Since I obviously cannot directly pass prop to `Home` from `Layout`, I will look into Context.

Comment: There is another method as well check my code.React.cloneElement where you can pass props to children

Comment: He not rendering Home within Layout like in your examples. He renders Layout within Home.

Comment: I know. Rendering layout 2 times is not the right approach. I already mentioned the context way is a good one. I just provide another alternative way. I don't know why its downvoted.

Comment: It's not about rendering twice, it's about you can't excess `props.isLightMode` in `Home`, try your example `isLightMode` is not valid in `Home`.

Comment: I don't understand if I clone the element and pass props then I can access those props to every child of the same level??

Comment: thanks @ShubhamVerma. I found the Context API to be perfect for this particular scenario.I will take a look at React.cloneElement as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it done by passing a callback function as a prop from the Home Component to the Layout Component, so as soon as the state of the isLightMode gets changed you can call that function and change the isLightMode value in the Home.

```
const Home = props => {
  return (
    <Layout
      onChangeMode={(mode) => setLightMode(mode)}
    >
      <img src={props.isLightMode ? AvatarLight : AvatarDark} />
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

So the toggleTheme will become,

```
toggleTheme() {
  this.setState(state => ({
    isLightMode: !state.isLightMode,
  }), () => {
    this.props.onChangeMode(this.state.isLightMode);
  })
}
```

In the Home Component, you will have to use useState hook or state to maintain the value of the isLightMode and pass it to the img tag from it.

Hope so this is what was required by you, and it solves your issue.

Comment: sorry i'm having a hard time understanding how `setLightMode` should be implemented from your example. It seems to imply that I need to modify my `Home` component so that it has its own `setLightMode` state that is different from the `setLightMode` state in `Layout`, correct?

Comment: What I used here is Hooks, or you can make Home component as Class component and give it state so that it can just use this.state.isLightMode

Via Hooks,

import React, {useState} from 'react'
...
const Home = props => {
const [isLightMode, setLightMode] = useState(true);
  return (
    <Layout onChangeMode={(mode) => setLightMode(mode)}>
      <img src={isLightMode ? AvatarLight : AvatarDark} />
    </Layout>
  )
}

In both cases, what I am trying is, to set the isLightMode variable value in Home component whenever it is being changed in the Layout component.

Comment: The OP wants access isLightMode in Home, you just passed a callback, you still can't access it.

Comment: @DennisVash how is what I suggested different from what you are doing. You are bringing the whole toggle function to the Layout, and I am passing the value back in Home whenever the isLIghtMode value getting changed. So it's accessible whenever he wants, in sync with the value of isLightMode that is in the Layout component. Can you please enlighten me how is it a wrong solution?

Answer (score 0):

## Solution using Context API:

Steps:

1. create `Context` object and `Context.Provider` component
2. wrap your root element in the `Context.Provider` component
3. use `contextType` property (or `Context.Consumer`) to consume `context`

**1. create `Context` object and `Context.Provider` component:**

```
import react from 'React'

const defaultValue = {
  isLightMode: true,
  toggleTheme: () => {},
}

// create Context object called ThemeContext
const ThemeContext = React.createContext(defaultState)

// create Context.Provider component called ThemeProvider
class ThemeProvider extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isLightMode: true,
  }

  toggleTheme = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const isLightMode = !this.state.isLightMode
    localStorage.setItem('isLightMode', JSON.stringify(isLightMode))
    this.setState({ isLightMode })
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const isLightMode = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('isLightMode'))
    if (isLightMode) {
      this.setState({ isLightMode })
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { children } = this.props
    const { isLightMode } = this.state

    return (
      <ThemeContext.Provider
        value={{
          isLightMode,
          toggleTheme: this.toggleTheme,
        }}
      >
        {children}
      </ThemeContext.Provider>
    )
  }

}
```

**2. wrap your root element in the `Context.Provider` component:**

```
import React from 'react'
import { ThemeProvider } from './src/context/ThemeContext'
export const wrapRootElement = ({ element }) => (
  <ThemeProvider>{element}</ThemeProvider>
)
```

**3. use `contextType` property to consume `context`:**

Home component

```
import React from 'react'
import Layout from '../layouts/layout'
import ThemeContext from '../context/ThemeContext'
import AvatarLight from '../../content/assets/img/avatar-light.png'
import AvatarDark from '../../content/assets/img/avatar-dark.svg'

export default class Home extends React.Component {
  static contextType = ThemeContext

  render() {
    const { isLightMode } = this.context
    return (
      <Layout>
        <img src={isLightMode ? AvatarLight : AvatarDark} />
      </Layout>
    )
  }
}
```

Navigation component

```
import React from 'react'
import Layout from '../layouts/layout'
import ThemeContext from '../context/ThemeContext'
import AvatarLight from '../../content/assets/img/avatar-light.png'
import AvatarDark from '../../content/assets/img/avatar-dark.svg'

export default class Home extends React.Component {
  static contextType = ThemeContext

  render() {
    const { isLightMode, toggleTheme } = this.context
    return (
      <nav>
        <a onClick={toggleTheme}>{isLightMode ? 'Light mode' : 'Dark mode'}</a>
      </nav>
    )
  }
}
```